# Output C++ code as assembly language in netbeans

Tags: c++, assembly, netbeans

I've looked around other threads for the answer.  But none of them have really broken down what needs to be done in the ide to view the assembly output.

Answer (score 2):

Try these after compiling your project:

- UNIX

> objdump -d a.out

- Windows

> dumpbin /DISASM a.exe

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NetBeans can show you an assembly code. For that you need:

- Compile your program with `-g` flag
- Open your source in `Editor` window and set a breakpoint (for example,
  on the `main` function)
- Start debugger by clicking `Debug Project` button or just hitting `Ctrl-F5`
- Open disassembly window by clicking `Window -> Debugging -> Disassembly` button, which becomes clickable only after you start the debugger

The NetBeans will open a new window with assembly code next to the `Editor` window with C++ source.